# Use SFML lib and include folder with git

Tags: github, visual-studio-2015, sfml

Me and my friend are working on a project, made with Visual Studio 2015. It's a game and we decided to use the SFML library, as it was the best choice. I have a book (published on oct. 2016 - so it's up to date with what we use and need). There were some instructions, from which 2 of them required me to specify the path to the lib and include folder. My question is: if we use github to work together on this project, how can I specify the path to the lib and include folder, without the need to constantly change (that would be my friend, who doesn't have the path I specified in the project proprieties) the path to lib and include, according to the PC he/I work(s) on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a path *relative* to your project.

If your project resides in `/Project` and your solution is `/Project/Project.sln` then you could just put the SFML folder in `/Project/SFML`. It will then end up in GIT, but maybe that's not a bad thing anyway.

Comment: *"It will then end up in GIT"* Which is not really required. Just don't add it and (optionally) add `SFML` to your `.gitignore` file. It's not a good idea to check in the whole SFML directory, because it might actually include unneded binary files (e.g. precompiled libraries, potentially its own git repository, etc.) you don't want in your project git as it's just "bloat".